# Using a variable as a dictionary key, is it possible?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with a corresponding value to each letter. I need to go through a string and calculate the sum of all letters' value.

```
    SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = {
'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10
} 
word = 'maths'
for letter in word:
    score += SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[letter]
```

The output `score` should be a sum of whatever value corresponding with the letters in `word`. But I can't get Python understand I'm calling a key by a variable type string.

What is your solution for this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The only thing wrong with that code is that you didn't initialize `score` to 0. Accessing the dict works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built in function `sum()` in python accepts comprehension. Your code can be simplified to:

```
SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 
                     'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 
                     'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 
                     'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 
                     'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10}

word = 'maths'
score = sum(SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[i] for i in word.lower()) # use lower for small letters

print(score)
```

And you get:

```
10
```

Comment: Thanks. I will go with your suggestion, as it appears the most elegant for me. Also, thanks for your help with lowercase `word` beforehand. Can you with advice on using built-in Python, how to train myself to start using func, like think about `sum` before `score +=` . Once again, thanks man.

Comment: @trangnguyen It comes with practice. Everyone here is learning. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

- You have forgotten to initialize `score` variable to 0.
- Code:

  ```
  SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 
                           'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 
                           'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 
                           'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 
                           'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10} 

  score = 0    #  ============ > the line to be added
  word = 'maths'
  for letter in word:
      score += SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[letter]

  print(score)
  ```
- Output:
  `10`
- If you do not initialize a variable you will get the following error: 
  `NameError: name 'variable' is not defined`... Which means you are using the variable before initializing it and it is wrong

Answer (score 2):

You can try map approach :

```
print(sum(map(lambda x:SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[x],word)))
```

output:

```
10
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the line `score = 0` before your for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `score` to zero before you use it

Answer (score -1):

Also, you might want to make the 'word' variable more dynamic by turning it into an input value:

```
SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 
                     'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8, 
                     'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 
                     'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1, 
                     'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10}

score = 0
#Make sure to force a lowercase
word = str(input("What word would you like to enter?").lower())
for letter in word:
     score += SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES[letter]
print(score)
```